# Implementation of Google Map on Blank Activity Not working

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I stuck into this problem since 3 days. I want to implement `Google Maps` on Blank activity created in android studio. what I did so far is

1. Got Google API key on google console
2. Put app name and SHA in that project on google console
3. Made an `xml` under Value folder and put API key there
4. Add Google play dependencies like

   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`
5. Add a Fragment in `main_activity.xml` file
6. Added Permissions in `AndroidMinifist.xml` file

**But** When I run the app it shows Fragment without Map
Here are my files

**Minifist file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pro.soft.inzi.mapapp11">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- The following two permissions are required for location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MapMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
}
```

**Map_main.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.pro.soft.inzi.mapapp11.MapMain"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_map_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And **MapMian.java**

```
public class MapMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_map_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What to do Please help what's wrong. I'm doing this because Google map template activity have no Title bar shown and I found no helpful solution of that also.

Any Suggestion / help.

Comment: i think you doesn't set main layout setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_main); instead of activity_main as you mention here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think almost everything is fine your code should work.
If not working still than Restart you `IDE` this may work for you.
**And** even if your code does not work after restart **then**
In the `XML` file, use first line instead of second as

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"  
// instead of   
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

And In you main class, use:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Instead of:

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

hope it will work for you.